# jmeter run in headless with 5000 user, which is better option to save results in CSV or XML or JTL

Tags: testing, load, performance-testing

Is it good to save the data, when jmeter running in high load and distributed load testing.
we are running the jmeter with 5000 users in AWS server. need to report the results of below.

1. throughput over time and over active users.
2. response time over TPS.
3. aggregate report.

So which is better option to save CSV or XML or JTL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JTL` is a common JMeter Test Log file extension, currently supported formats are `csv` and `xml`

Generally it is better to use `csv` format where possible (by the way, it is default format) as generating XML is more resource intensive. Good practice is stick to `csv` output and temporarily switch to `xml` in case when you need to inspect request/response details for debugging/troubleshooting purposes.

So make sure you have the following entry in *user.properties* file:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv
```

For distributed execution it is also important to choose the appropriate [sample sender](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html#sendermode) to limit the data being sent from slaves to master to necessary minimum. The recommended value is

```
mode=StrippedBatch
```

however this mode removes response data from successful samplers so your [PostProcesors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and/or [Assertions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#assertions) may stop working.

References:

- [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
- [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure)